# Assembly not packaged for Azure worker role

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, package, azure-worker-roles

I am facing a strange problem with packaging an assembly for Azure worker role. I am building a sample Azure cloud application having one website and a worker role. I am referencing a third party assembly, `myasm.dll` in both website and worker role project. The `myasm.dll` has dependency on two other assemblies. When I build the project all three(myasm.dll and two dependent assemblies) third party assemblies are getting copied to bin directory for both website and worker role projects. So far so good.

When packaging is done for worker role, off the three third party assemblies, only two assemblies are included in the package, the third assembly is not included. Strangely enough, packaging of Website project includes all three assemblies. I created one more worker role to test the behavior but same behavior was seen again.

Is this a known issue or something? Any help is highly appreciated.

I use VS2012 Update 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package will not include any dll which is not explicitly used in your project or referenced. I know this problem occurs when you do not use type explicitly in a your project([old bug raised](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/731303/publish-web-feature-not-including-all-dlls) - with won't fix status)

I guess your best option is to explicitly reference those missing dll's ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683672.aspx#IncludeFiles)) or try to add dummy usage of types from missing dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. The types I use from myasm.dll and the code is same for both website and worker role projects. So I am wondering why myasm.dll gets packaged for website but not for worker role.

Comment: It's just the packaging bug. Visual Studio has correctly pulled in all the required assemblies to application's bin directory. But the packaging utility decides not to package one of the assembly. Unable to understand how the packaging utility determines one of the assembly is not required